# Rails Byebug Did Not Stop Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, byebug

I want to use byebug to debug my application but the app is never stop although I already put `byebug` inside my code. Here is my Gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console

  gem 'byebug', '~> 5.0.0'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

end
```

I put `byebug` in one of my controller.

```
def edit
  byebug
  present Ingredient::Update
end
```

I already made all my request local in my `development.rb`. I already restart the server a couple times.

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```

Here is the example stack trace that `byebug` only print the first trace and then the app keeps going on executing the next line.

```
web_1 | [43, 52] in /recipe/app/controllers/ingredients_controller.rb
web_1 |    43:   def update
web_1 |    44:     run Ingredient::Update do |op|
web_1 |    45:       return redirect_to op.model
web_1 |    46:     end
web_1 |    47:     byebug
web_1 | => 48:     render action: :edit
web_1 |    49:   end
web_1 |    50:
web_1 |    51:   # DELETE /ingredients/1
web_1 |    52:   # DELETE /ingredients/1.json
web_1 | (byebug)   Rendered ingredients/edit.haml within layouts/application (264.1ms)
web_1 |   Rendered layouts/_navigation.haml (45.0ms)
web_1 | Completed 200 OK in 2827ms (Views: 2764.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)
web_1 |
web_1 |
web_1 | Started GET "/assets/application.self-1ca8529ef221ef9dba25e835f258c4e62f2f49bce400273a67e63d7d73be28ba.css?body=1" for 192.168.59.3 at 2015-07-28 06:46:00 +0000
```

Any idea?
**Update**
I use docker-compose and docker inside my Rails app.

Comment: Just restart the server and check.

Comment: Restart you application server

Comment: Yes, I already restart the server a couple times

Comment: Update I use docker-compose and docker inside my Rails app.

Comment: Wow. I'm seeing the exact same behavior, except without Docker being involved.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

When using `docker-compose` in combination with `byebug` this needs to be added to make it work properly. Found in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@ddomachine/docker-and-ruby-on-rails-448ab8255f97)

Add this to docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  ...
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
```

Then run docker-compose in deamonized mode and attach to the web container with docker:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker attach myappname_web_1
```

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to run your services in detached mode. Also when you attach to the container, it'll appear as if it's hanging, but as soon as that container's app receives a request, you'll see logger output.

Comment: Do not use docker attach myappname_web_1. Instead, run "docker container ls" to get the containers running, and then find the id of the one you are working on. Then, just run: "docker attach container_id"

Comment: What to do if it does not halt on the actual instruction? It just prints it out and continues executing

Comment: Can someone explain why it doesn't work when container name is provided instead of id as mentioned in the comment above?

Answer (score 18):

To enable debugger mode:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports web
```

See this [blog post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2015/03/17/docker-rails-docker-compose-together-in-your-development-workflow/)

Comment: great! It works without needing to add `stdin_open` and `tty`