# Using remote byebug instance with docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, docker, docker-compose, byebug

Is there a way to setup a rails server so that you can connect with a remote byebug server and debug easily? I've done this in the past by setting up byebug and then enabling a rails bind on 0.0.0.0 and setting a VIRTUAL_PORT=3000 but I was wondering if there were other easier ways to debug an already running container. I looked into https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/ but wasn't able to get it setup properly.

Answer (score 4):

See this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32690885/2329984). Do note that running your services in `detached` mode isn't necessary. Also when attaching to the rails container, it'll appear as if nothing happened in your terminal until you make a request to the rails application.